# How to give option for switch account on Instagram API?

Tags: instagram-api

I am using Instagram API, user can login with their account and i can use their access token for all endpoints. Once the user logged in, in browser session exist. How to give option for user to switch between Instagram accounts.

login -> 1 account -> switch account -> because of previous session it's again login with same account without confirmation.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: when you mention switching accounts, do you mean logging in to a different account?

Comment: Yes, authorize with different account.

Comment: without more information there isn't much I can help you with. it sounds like you're not properly authenticating the second account. at some point you're going to have to switch authentication from one user to the next and I don't think you're doing it properly

Comment: Did you worked with Instagram API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have logout from instagram. Opening URL `"https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/"` will log user out of instagram.

You have to do this before you give this option to login again

One way I did it on https://www.picodash.com was to open a hidden `iframe` with this URL and it will logout, (jquery code)

```
$('#content').append('<div style="display:none"><iframe src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0"></iframe></div>');
```

So when give the option to add second account, run the above code before you allow the user to click login button